# Satisfy the schrodinger equation using this wave function with the borders

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation

> Given the wave function
> $$
>  \Psi(x,t) = \left\{
>         \begin{array}{ll}
>             A\cdot \sin(\frac{2\pi x}{a})\cdot\exp\big(\frac{-iE\cdot t}{\hbar}\big)  &,-\frac{a}{2}  \lt  x \lt \frac{a}{2}\\
>             0 & ,x  \lt  -\frac{a}{2} \text{ or }  x \gt \frac{a}{2}
>         \end{array}
> \right.
> $$
> $i)$ Show that the wave function above satisfies the Schrödinger equation.

So, I tried it this way:

[image]

1. Change in Schrödinger function
2. Differentiate with respect to $x$ and $t$
3. Insert the derivatives into Schroedinger equation

Is the final result correct? I think doesn't exist this function for $E$, but I don't have a good answer to explain this.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Please avoid screenshots in general, and bad-quality ones in particular. Type the relevent part of the computation using Mathjax provided here. Also, "check my homework" questions are too vague and aren't welcome here. Be as specific as possible.

Comment: The points is the final answer about E, i reach the finish, but can't explain why the function sastify or no the schrodinger equation

Comment: So, i'm editing with mathjax the print, thanks for the tips! (:

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is almost correct, it just has an extra negative sign and is missing a factor of Plank's constant. Regardless, your process is correct. Here, I'll suggest a faster way of getting to the answer.

When one has an eigenstate of the Hamiltonian, $\hat{H} \Psi(x) = E\Psi(x)$, the complete wavefunction also dependant on time is given by $\Psi(x,t) = \Psi(x) \cdot \exp\big(\frac{-iE\cdot t}{\hbar})$. (This comes from considering the time dependent Schrödinger equation acting on an energy eigenstate). So look at the wavefunction you have been given for $|x| < \frac{a}{2}$:
$$\Psi(x,t) = A\cdot \sin(\frac{2\pi x}{a})\cdot\exp\big(\frac{-iE\cdot t}{\hbar})$$
All you must show is there exists some Hamiltonian operator that has $A\cdot \sin(\frac{2\pi x}{a})$ as an eigenfunction. It is pretty well known that the second derivate has sine as an eigenfunction. So start from the eigenvalue equation
$$\frac{d^2}{dx^2} A \sin(\frac{2\pi x}{a}) = E \cdot A \sin(\frac{2\pi x}{a})  $$
Cancel $A$ from both sides and apply the derivatives on the left,
$$-(\frac{4\pi^2}{a^2}) \sin(\frac{2\pi x}{a}) = E \cdot \sin(\frac{2\pi x}{a})  $$
And so we have shown $A\cdot \sin(\frac{2\pi x}{a})$ is an eigenvalue of the operator $\frac{d^2}{dx^2}$ with eigenvalue $E = -\frac{4\pi^2}{a^2}$. Hence there does exist the Hamiltonian we sought and so the wave function is a solution to the Schrödinger equation (when also considering that it is zero on the rest of the real numbers is a trivial solution).

Notice we get something very much like your result if we take the more physically meaningful Hamiltonian of a free particle
$$\hat{H} = - \frac{\hbar^2}{2m} \frac{d^2}{dx^2}$$
This of course gives an eigenvalue that is a scaling of what we got last time:
$$\boxed{E = - \frac{\hbar^2}{2m} \cdot-\frac{4\pi^2}{a^2} = \frac{4\hbar^2 \pi^2}{2ma^2} }$$
**You can find this energy expression in any quantum mecahnics textbook as the energy of a free particle in an infinite potential well with width $a$ centered at $x = $ (this is the wavefunction you have been given, so it is indeed a real scenario).**